# React-Quill delta to html with custom css without using any package

Tags: html, reactjs, quill, react-quill

I'm using react-quill as a text editor and then sending its `delta.ops` object to my backend.
Now I want to generate HTML from that `delta.ops` in the frontend without using any external package/library.
I tried some PHP approach from one of the solutions available but the problem is that by doing so I'm not able to add my custom styling to those elements.

suppose I have `<strong>hello</strong>` now I want to change its font-size and maybe color but unable to do so.

Any help would be appreciated.